# Swift : use of unresolved identifier

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm trying to make a flappy bird clone and I am getting this message... "use of unresolved identifier for 'Ghost'." The error is occuring in the touches began function. I'm knew to all this so I don't really know what's going. I was following a tutorial coded in swift 2.1 so I'm not sure if that may be a problem, but I'm almost sure I copied it line for line.

```
import SpriteKit


struct PhysicsCategory {
    static var Ghost : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    static var Ground : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
    static var Wall : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
}


class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

    var Ground = SKSpriteNode()
    var Ghost = SKSpriteNode()


    Ground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ground")
    Ground.setScale(0.5)
    Ground.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y:0 + Ground.frame.height/2)

    Ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Ground.size)
    Ground.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ground
    Ground.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ghost
    Ground.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ghost
    Ground.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false


    self.addChild(Ground)



    Ghost = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ghost")
    Ghost.size = CGSize(width:60, height: 70)
    Ghost.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2 - Ghost.frame.width, y: self.frame.height/2)
    Ghost.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: Ghost.frame.height/2)
    Ghost.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ghost
    Ghost.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ground | PhysicsCategory.Wall
    Ghost.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ground | PhysicsCategory.Wall
    Ghost.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    Ghost.physicsBody?.dynamic = true




    self.addChild(Ghost)


    createWalls()
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    Ghost.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0,0)
    Ghost.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 60))



}


func createWalls() {

    let wallPair = SKNode()

    let topWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Wall")
    let bottomWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Wall")

    topWall.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y:self.frame.height/2 + 350)
    bottomWall.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y:self.frame.height/2 - 350)

    topWall.setScale(0.5)
    bottomWall.setScale(0.5)

    topWall.zRotation = CGFloat(M_PI)

    wallPair.addChild(topWall)
    wallPair.addChild(bottomWall)

    self.addChild(wallPair)


}


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Ghost` is not a data type; it's the name of a single variable that you create in your `didMoveToView()` method. You need to make it a property of your class so that it can still be initialized in `didMoveToView()`, but used in other methods, like `touchesBegan()`. Just move your `var Ghost` declaration outside of the method, and keep the `Ghost = SKSpriteNode(...)` where it is.

It should also be mentioned that it's a really bad idea to have a local variable or a property have the same name as one of your `enum` cases; anybody who reads the code could get understandably confused, even though they're perfectly legal as far as the compiler is concerned. It's also not very Swift-like to capitalize your variable or property names.

And lastly, I have to implore you **not** to create another Flappy Bird clone! We have enough of those to last a lifetime.